# SectionList scrollToLocation cannot scroll in React Native Web

Tags: react-native-web

I'm using `SectionList` provided in the [react-native-web](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web)

Issue: SectionList won't scroll to a Sectionindex using `scrollToLocation()`

The same works in React Native (android and iOS) but doesn't work for the web.

Sample code https://snack.expo.io/@jijobose/90baef

Comment: Hi have you ever found a solution to this?